# Retaining Wall Supported by Fence

Tags: fence, retaining-wall

I am working on building a 1.5ft retaining wall in between my yard and my neighbors yard. There was a previously a wood retaining wall but was poorly designed and blown out and I am replacing it.

My question is: Is it okay to use the metal fence posts to hold my retaining wall? The fence posts are ~6ft apart. The wall will be made of 2x12 and a 2x6 on top.

I figured with a good gravel base and being such a small wall to start, it would be okay but wanted to get some other peoples opinions.[image]

Comment: who owns the fence?

Comment: That's a good question. I think it is the neighbors, it was there before both of us bought the properties, however on the survey it says "adj's fnc", although it looks like it overlaps my side slightly.

Comment: From the direction the fence is facing and the matching fence in the rear of the photo, it looks like your fence.... In any case, I don't think you want to use the same posts for the retaining wall. For one reason, if the fence is removed or replaced, your retaining wall goes with it. The "proper" way would be to build it as a free-standing wall.